# Strange result of actual title: Actual title displayed wrong in web driver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Expected title is "Welcome: mercury Tours"

But in Actual Title displayed as a Webdriver, so that script failed

I used thread too still it displayed Actual title is Web driver

This issue occurred in IE browser,script passed in Firefox.

Comment: Could you share the code that you have written for this scenario?

Comment: Even without a single line of your code I can see that the problem is in your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this website:
http://newtours.demoaut.com/
then the actual title is "**Welcome: Mercury Tours**"

Try using this:

```
String actual= driver.getTitle();
String expected = "Welcome: mercury Tours";
Assert.assertEquals(actual, expected);
```

Since your expected is "Welcome: mercury Tours" which is different from the actual "Welcome: Mercury Tours", the test will fail, no matter which browser.

Comment: Could help you more, if you share the code you've written

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is genuine since i experienced same problem at one scenario. While using IE browser with robot framework, initially the browser bar title is shown as "webdriver" instead of expected title. My suggestion is wait until your page loads. Keep driver instance wait until your locator(take some locator in your web page) is visible.

--> Least preference is keep some thread sleep

I hope it will be useful. Let me know if there is any issue

Comment: I already used thread.sleep, still its not working in IE. Same code is running on firefox.